# The smallest sequence which distinguishes samples from each other

Tags: r, sequence

I have 5 bacteria genome fasta files and I need to find the smallest sequence for each of the sample which will distinguish it from the others. I don't know if there is a package to do it or should I write my own code. There is a big question on my way,can you guide me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Ask in https://www.biostars.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a more elegant/faster way to do this, but here's one possibility using base R (assuming I understood your question correctly)

```
#generate example sequenes
seqs.to.check <- lapply(sample(10:20, 10), 
function(x) sample(letters, x, replace=TRUE))

#get list of lists of all sub-sequences for each example sequence
all.sub.seqs <- lapply(seqs.to.check, function(seq){
  sub.seqs <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(seq)) for(j in 0:(length(seq) - i)) sub.seqs[[length(sub.seqs) + 1]] <- seq[i:(i+j)]
  sub.seqs
})

#get list of lists of minimum length distinct sub-sequences for example sequence
min.distinct.seqs <- lapply(seq_along(seqs.to.check), function(seq.i){
  #extract sub-sequences of sequence to check
  sub.seqs <- all.sub.seqs[[seq.i]]
  #extract all sub-sequences of other sequences
  other.sub.seqs <- unlist(all.sub.seqs[-seq.i], recursive=FALSE)
  #identify indices for which no matching sub-sequence can be found
  no.match.indices <- which(sapply(sub.seqs, function(x) Position(function(z) identical(z, x), other.sub.seqs, nomatch=0))==0)
  #return a list of the shortest non-matching sub-sequences
  lengths.no.matches <- unlist(lapply(sub.seqs[no.match.indices], length))                   
  sub.seqs[no.match.indices][lengths.no.matches == min(lengths.no.matches)]
})
```

Comment: Yes,I need to use R to solve this problem. Thank you for your attention. That's what I am looking for!